# How would a website detect that I'm using a SSH tunnel?

Tags: security, web, ssh, proxy, vpn

I have a shared hosting account with SSH access, so I often use it as a SSH tunnel to browse websites securely and anonymously. But some times, a website would detect that I'm using a SSH tunnel and not allow me to use their services. For example, today I visited a site, that just flat out told me "Use of Proxie/VPN/VPS/Tor is not allowed.", now this is a very small site, I don't think it has a database of all proxies in the world. So I guess this must be possible in website programming to achieve detection of proxies/ssh tunnel/vpn.

So my question is, how is this detection done? and is there anything I could do to avoid detection? Thanks.

Comment: The wikipedia article for Proxy Server (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_server#Detection) gives some methods of detecting whether data is being proxied

Comment: In adition to mfanto's answer, there are also companies that offer proxy IP data for a fee.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found what I wanted to know with the link provided by mfanto's comment, the link is:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_server#Detection